# Create new type of shared properties of multiple types

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Is it possible to create a new type out of the shared properties of different types?

Example:

```
type A = {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  description: string; 
}
   
type B = {
  text: string;
  description: string;
  value: number;
}
```

and my target type would look like this

```
type C = {
  text: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without creating the type manually?

Comment: What is the expected result for types like `{x: number}` and `{x: string}`?

Comment: Good question, probably that last type wins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the result value type for same keys with different value types should be their union:

```
type Common<T1, T2> = Pick<T1 | T2, Extract<keyof T1, keyof T2>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCWATAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcaUwEAHsHgM7AUb4DmN6WELAMYcwwDAHt8rdpx5QUAX1rzQkKACEEyWvSbSO3XlH5CRYyftlGAbgEMANoQh4iZSjSUpV0AMLjixJIAPAAqAIwANFAhAEwAfFoAChiCANahYVAAPtExUQCiTBS2gsBBqRAg4gBm0ZFQFVW1sXFxKF7gvlp+AcEwUepxNCgA9CN0nVA+Wqhj6HSMzFBsBjyj43wCwhiiElLLMobrUApAA)

---

We [extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the common keys, then [pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) them from union of two types.